# Internet is Fine When Connect Through Router and Not Through the Modem

Tags: networking, router, internet, modem

And no: I didn't confuse a router for a modem.

When I have my ethernet cord plugged into my laptop from the modem itself, I get no Internet, and no gateway.  However, when I connect it through a Netgear router it works fine.  I've Googled this and all the responses are the exact opposite of this issue.

I've never encountered something like this before, please help.

Comment: Many ISP "modems" (which are usually pretty much just locked down/bridged routers these days), lock themselves to the first device they are plugged into (identified by the MAC address), and will not give an IP to any other device until it's been fully reset.  Talk to your ISP about it.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Reset as in paper clip in pinhole reset?

Comment: Basically yeah, a factory-level reset.  How you do that depends on your device.   Note, the in some cases it won't be enough, and it will require the ISP to release the existing MAC they have on file.  Again, discuss it with them, as they'll know best.  With the info you've provided us here, there isn't really enough to give you any more specific advice.